# Can I use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker to request access to the Google Sheets API in a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-drive-api, windows-phone-8.1, google-docs, google-docs-api

The [.NET client libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list) for [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#additional_resources_and_information_about_this_guide) have not been updated since Jun 2013, and so cannot be added to a Windows Phone 8.1 application. However, Google has published an [Auth NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) that works with Google Drive (and other Google services) and *does* support Windows Phone 8.1.

In the [example for using OAuth 2 with Windows Phone 8.1](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#wp81), they demonstrate requesting `DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly` as a way to list the files available in Google Drive. However, I cannot find any similarly-named constants for Google Sheets, and there does not appear to be any Google Docs-related NuGet packages.

Can I use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` to also request app access to Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

The [Google Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#about_authorization_protocols) says that the "scope information for the Google Sheets API" is located at `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds`.

Updating the [sample](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#wp81) (Step 6c) to

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                  new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
                  new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,

                         // Add our new scope here...
                         "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" },

                  "app-name",
                  CancellationToken.None);
```

will give the application access to Google Sheets.

Unfortunately, after that you have to make the call to the Sheets API manually, so remember to include

- `v=3.0` in the query string itself or `GData-Version: 3.0` as a header [(link)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#specifying_a_version).
- [an `Authorization` header](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#callinganapi) in the form of `Bearer {AccessToken}`. The `AccessToken` be grabbed from

  - `credential.Token` in `AuthenticateAsync` after `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` returns.
  - any time after login in `(service.HttpClientInitializer as Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential).Token`.